# Servlet class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet

Tags: jetty, java-17, gretty, jakarta-ee-9

Can anyone say me what is the main cause of reason for the below error?

i am using gretty as a plugin to run my war file using jetty. Following is my configuration in a gradle file for it. I am also using java17 here

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.gretty'
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    scanInterval = 2
//    servletContainer = 'tomcat10'
    servletContainer = 'jetty11'
}

war {
    archiveFileName = "configapi.war"
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '3.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '3.1.3'
//    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.15.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs', name: 'jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider', version: '2.16.1'
    implementation(group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-bean-validation', version: '3.1.3') {
//        exclude(group: 'javax.el', module: 'javax.el-api')
//        exclude(group: 'jakarta.el', module: 'jakarta.el-api')
    }
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.13.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.5'
    implementation 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-contribs:1.19'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    implementation 'org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.8.3'
    implementation(group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16')
    implementation(group: 'log4j', name: 'apache-log4j-extras', version: '1.1')
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:3.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '3.1.3'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '32.1.3-jre'
    implementation group: 'com.github.java-json-tools', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '2.2.14'

//    implementation group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '5.0.1'
//    implementation group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'jakarta.el', version: '4.0.2'

    implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: '3.3.6') {
        exclude(group: 'com.sun.jersey')
        exclude(group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', module: 'jsp-api')
        exclude(group: 'jakarta.servlet', module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(group: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp', module: 'jsp-api')
    }
//    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.servlet', name: 'jakarta.servlet-api', version: '5.0.0'

    /** added for unit tests **/
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '3.1.3'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.5.0'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-grizzly2-http', version: '3.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.grizzly', name: 'grizzly-http-servlet', version: '4.0.0'
//    testImplementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    testImplementation group: 'jakarta.validation', name: 'jakarta.validation-api', version: '3.0.2'
//    testImplementation group: 'org.glassfish.web', name: 'javax.el', version: '2.2.6'
    testImplementation group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '5.0.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.apache.curator', name: 'curator-test', version: '5.2.0'
}

test {
    exclude '**/*restapis/services/v*/*Test.class'
    include '**/*Test.class'
    include '**/TestAll.class'
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectVersion", version
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    }
}
```

When i tried to run command gradle
`:configapi:CodeGenerator:configapi:jettyRunWar`. It gave me following error:

```
oag.JettyConfigurerImpl:main: Error starting server jakarta.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet is not a jakarta.servlet.Servlet.
```

Can someone help me out why i am getting this issue here.

I tried to make compatible with jetty11 by updating the gradle file below but still i am getting same error

```html
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'org.gretty'
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    scanInterval = 2
//    servletContainer = 'tomcat10'
    servletContainer = 'jetty11'
}

war {
    archiveFileName = "configapi.war"
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '3.0.2'
//    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.15.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs', name: 'jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider', version: '2.16.1'
    implementation(group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext', name: 'jersey-bean-validation', version: '3.0.2') {
//        exclude(group: 'javax.el', module: 'javax.el-api')
//        exclude(group: 'jakarta.el', module: 'jakarta.el-api')
    }
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.13.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.5'
    implementation 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-contribs:1.19'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    implementation 'org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.8.3'
    implementation(group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16')
    implementation(group: 'log4j', name: 'apache-log4j-extras', version: '1.1')
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '32.1.3-jre'
    implementation group: 'com.github.java-json-tools', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '2.2.14'

//    implementation group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '5.0.1'
//    implementation group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'jakarta.el', version: '4.0.2'

    implementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: '3.3.6') {
        exclude(group: 'com.sun.jersey')
        exclude(group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', module: 'jsp-api')
        exclude(group: 'jakarta.servlet', module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(group: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp', module: 'jsp-api')
    }
//    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.servlet', name: 'jakarta.servlet-api', version: '5.0.0'

    /** added for unit tests **/
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '3.0.2'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '5.5.0'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-grizzly2-http', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.grizzly', name: 'grizzly-http-servlet', version: '4.0.0'
//    testImplementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    testImplementation group: 'jakarta.validation', name: 'jakarta.validation-api', version: '3.0.2'
//    testImplementation group: 'org.glassfish.web', name: 'javax.el', version: '2.2.6'
    testImplementation group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '5.0.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.apache.curator', name: 'curator-test', version: '5.2.0'
}

test {
    exclude '**/*restapis/services/v*/*Test.class'
    include '**/*Test.class'
    include '**/TestAll.class'
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectVersion", version
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some version mismatches. For example, Eclipse Jersey 3.1 that you use is for Jakarta EE 10, but you are using Servlet 5 from Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: By the way, Log4J 1 is [now end-of-life](https://news.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces)

Comment: By the way, Jetty 11 is [now at end-of-support](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10485) too.

Comment: Jersey 3.1 would require Jetty 12 and it's ee10 environment.

Comment: What would the correct gradle file look like then? @JoakimErdfelt

Comment: I tried to make compatible with jetty 11 but still i am getting same error.

Comment: I just figured out the issue. It was of transitive dependency. dependency hadoop-client also included jetty-servlet dependency of version jetty-servlet-9.4.51.v20230217. By excluding it the issue was fixed. Thanks